# Aggregate JSON values by keys

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a bunch of dynamic survey results stored in a table with a JSON column that looks like so:

```
{"regional":"never","local":"sometimes","personal":"often","bike":"field_4","walk":"field_5","carpool":"field_4","carshare":"often","rideshare":"sometimes"}
```

The keys are values that exist dynamically throughout the dataset. I need to find an efficient way to aggregate the keys and count the correlated results. This data represents a Likert scale survey question ie.

"How often do you go to the bus station? Not Often, Sometimes, Very Often"

The resulting dataset I'd like to produce is:

```
{
    "regional": { "sometimes": 20, "often": 10, "never": 5 },
    "bike": { "sometimes": 20, "often": 10, "never": 5 }
    "walk": { "sometimes": 20, "often": 10, "never": 5 }
}
```

I've attempted JSON_EACH to break the values into key/value pairs but I'm now having trouble aggregating the keys and frequency of potential results. This is what I have so far:

```
  SELECT
    json_data.key,
    json_data.value
  FROM
    "SubmissionData" AS sd,
    JSON_EACH_TEXT(sd.data) AS json_data
  WHERE
    sd.key = 'transit'
```

Definitely hit a roadblock here though.

Thanks.

Comment: Sample data and desired outcome?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`json_object_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html), e.g.:

```
with my_table(data) as (
values
    ('{"regional":"never","local":"sometimes","personal":"often"}'::json),
    ('{"regional":"often","local":"sometimes","personal":"often"}'::json)
)

select json_object_agg(key, vals)
from (
    select key, json_object_agg(value, count) vals
    from (
        select key, value, count(*)
        from
            my_table,
            json_each_text(data)
        group by 1, 2
        ) s
    group by 1
    ) s;

                                              json_object_agg                                               
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 { "regional" : { "never" : 1, "often" : 1 }, "personal" : { "often" : 2 }, "local" : { "sometimes" : 2 } }
(1 row)
```

Comment: Damn that was fast! I'll give this a test and mark your answer =)